# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated in linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, email, smtp

Hi i want send a mail from my linux server my code block/project is working in my local(windows) but i get this error when i run my project in linux.

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
```

Here is my code block where is my problem? thanks.

```
                string domain = "my.local";
                string userName = "info";
                string userPass = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AkXyz2*"));
                string host = "mail.mymail.com.tr";
                string fromMail = "mymail@mymail.com.tr";
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                var smtp = new SmtpClient(host, 587);//port
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, userPass, domain);
                smtp.Credentials = credentials;
                smtp.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;
                ...
                ...
                smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: A common arrangement is to have an unencrypted listener on port 587 and then pivot to TLS only after STARTTLS; but these things depend on local conventions, and I'm just vaguely guessing that the error message might be misleading (it's Microsoft, isn't it?). If you can tweak up debugging levels so we can see what the server is actually responding, that would probably help pinpoint where exactly this is going wrong.

Comment: i can not  tweak up debugging sir cause just deploy my code in linux server it is running in there is tere any suggestion for tweak up debugging? cause i can not get any error in my local windows operating system.

Comment: Most SMTP libraries have a simple way to control this but it seems like Microsoft's documentation at least does not make it obvious how to do that. If this works on one computer but not on another, I would suspect a network error of some sort. Did you try removing the TLS stuff just to see what happens?

Comment: i tried sir my local is working but linux is same error again.